# 2 conformal maps doing same shape changing seem not equal

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$f(z)=\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ would map the upper half disk to the first quadrant. While $g(z)=z^2$ would map the first quadrant to the upper half plane. On the other hand, $h(z)=-\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})$ would also do the same for mapping the upper half disk to the upper half plane. Yet, composition of $f$ followed by $g$ is not the same as $h$. Is it normal?

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely expected.  They differ only by an automorphism of the upper half space.  Specifically, the map
$$
k\colon w\mapsto\frac{w-1}{w+1}
$$
satisfies $kh=gf$

*How did we come up with this $k$?*

Look at the boundary (or rather points near it and take limit).
$gf$ has the effect mapping $0\mapsto 1$, $-1\mapsto 0$ and $1\mapsto\infty$, and $h$ has the effect mapping $0\mapsto\infty$, $-1\mapsto 1$ and $1\mapsto -1$
So you want a Mobius map sending $\infty,1,-1$ to $1,0,\infty$ and that is the map $k$ above.

*Verifying $kh=gf$*

Indeed, you can check
$$
\begin{align*}
(k\circ h)(z)
&=\frac{h(z)-1}{h(z)+1}\\
&=\frac{-2zh(z)+2z}{-2zh(z)-2z}\\
&=\frac{z^2+2z+1}{z^2-2z+1}\\
&=(g\circ f)(z)
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! A good way to interpret by Mobius map.